# How to read json string from kafka topic into pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am trying to read json message from Kafka topic into PySpark dataframe. My first take was this:

```py
consumer = KafkaConsumer(TOPIC_NAME,
                             consumer_timeout_ms=9000,
                             bootstrap_servers=BOOTSTRAP_SERVER,
                             auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                             enable_auto_commit=True,
                             group_id=str(uuid4()),
                             value_deserializer=lambda x: x.decode("utf-8"))
message_lst = []
    for message in consumer:
        message_str = message.value.replace('\\"', "'").replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")
        message_dict = json.loads(message_str)
        message_lst.append(message_dict)

    messages_json = sc.parallelize(message_lst)
    messages_df = sqlContext.read.json(messages_json)
```

I am wondering is there a way to get the same dataframe using Spark structured streaming or something similar. Can anybody help?
UPD: My try with structured streaming was this:

```py
df = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", f"{BOOTSTRAP_SERVER}") \
        .option("subscribe", TOPIC_NAME) \
        .load()
```

It exited with the following error:
`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: Kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".`
UPD: I read the guide, that was stated in Exception text, it recommends installing this library "spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12", but I can't find one.  Does anyone know something about this?
UPD 2: I managed to add needed package and tried this to read messages from kafka:

```py
df = spark \
...         .readStream \
...         .format("kafka") \
...         .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", f"{BOOTSTRAP_SERVER}") \
...         .option("subscribe", TOPIC_NAME) \
...         .load()
df.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start().awaitTermination()
```

I used the same consumer as before. The problem here is that it only reads the messages, that are written after the start() call. How can I read all message that was written at a given time and get results as dataframe? Also, can anybody give an example of the schema for load_json()? I am sorry if my questions are stupid, but I cant find any examples in Python.

Comment: This should help: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html. It shows how to read a Kafka stream using Spark Structured Streaming. In the examples the values are read as strings, but you can easily interpret them as json using the built-in function `from_json`

Comment: So, you know about Structured Streaming, but it's unclear what you've tried

Comment: @OneCricketeer Updated the question; check it one more time, please.

Comment: What do you mean you couldn't find it? It's a Maven package, not Python https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the kafka package as mentioned in the [main documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#deploying)

```sh
./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2 ...
```

Make sure that 3.1.2 listed here matches your own Spark version

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer, it helped me solve the issue, but I faced new ones. I updated the question; please, check it one more time